# How do I "undo" "return false;" for following links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I know this question has been asked before, but I still can't make it work.

There's a nested list which is used as an index/navigation. It is 4 levels deep, with links on the fourth level. The higher levels are toggled using jQuery. To make the javascript work, I have to use "return false;". But then the links don't work.

How do I make the links on the fourth level work again, i.e. "return true;"?

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>nav 1
    <ul>
      <li>nav 1.1
        <ul>
          <li>nav 1.1.1
            <ul>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">google</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://amazon.com">amazon</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("li ul").hide();

  $("li").click(function() {

    //if li-element has class "active" 
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { 

      //remove "active" class from li-element
      $(this).has( "ul" ).removeClass("active");

      //remove "active" class from child li-elements
      $(this).has( "ul" ).find('li').removeClass("active");

      //hide nested ul-elements
      $(this).has( "ul" ).find("ul").slideUp("fast");

    else { //if li-element has no class "active"
      //remove "active" class from adjacent li-elements
      $(this).has( "ul" ).siblings('li').removeClass("active");
      $(this).has( "ul" ).siblings('li').find('li').removeClass("active");

      //hide nested ul-elements from adjacent li-elements         
      $(this).has( "ul" ).siblings('li').find("ul").slideUp("fast");  

      //add "active" class to li-element         
      $(this).has( "ul" ).addClass("active");

      //show nested ul-element
      $(this).has( "ul" ).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
    }     

    return false;
  });

  //this doesn't work :-(       
  $(".nav > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a").click(function(){
    return true;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the event from bubbling. It's simple.

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

in place of:

```
//this doesn't work :-(       
$(".nav > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a").click(function(){
  return true;
});
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Heard of preventDefault, but stopPropagation was new to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's better for you to separate stop links into some class. For example

```
<li><a class="dummy" href="http://google.com">google</a></li>
<li><a class="dummy" href="http://amazon.com">amazon</a></li>
```

Add some js

```
$('a.dummy').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And remove `return false` from your `li` event handler.

Comment: Can you explain why `return false;` should be removed? I tried that just now and I could only toggle the nav, but not advance further into the menu.

Comment: Same question here. Tried it without return false, but then li-elements don't toggle anymore. Also tried preventDefault before, but somehow it doesn't work (don't know why, because you're answer totally makes sense to me. Thanks anyway!)